# Turbo boost present or not?

Tags: laptop, turbo-boost

I bought a Samsung NP550P5C-S05IN laptop recently with a i7 3630QM processor. According to the specs its capable of turbo boost but when I check the bios there is no option for it. Should I be checking somewhere else or do I have a defective laptop?

Answer (score 0):

download CUP-Z tool (http://www.cpuid.com/downloads/cpu-z/1.66-en.zip) run it and check if your laptop is truely running with 3630QM processor. If yes, everything just fine. There are no fake intel processor.

If you want for sure, try to run a heavy-load program and see if your cpu core speed meet 3.4 GHz (your CPU maximum speed) http://ark.intel.com/products/71459

> Intel® Turbo Boost Technology dynamically increases the processor's
>   frequency as needed by taking advantage of thermal and power headroom
>   to give you a burst of speed when you need it, and increased energy
>   efficiency when you don’t.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the Intel boost widget. It shows much of your CPU you are using. FYI the Intel turbo boost kicks in when you use 98% of your CPU. So if your CPU speed is 2.5ghz when you run a load of 90%(not sure about this percentage) on your CPU the turbo boost would increase you speed to 2.8ghz.

Source personal experience.